# Return value of a window procedure

Tags: windows, winapi

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx), the return value of a user-defined window procedure is described this way:

> The return value is the result of the message processing and depends
>   on the message sent.

This doesn't help much. Should I return 0 after I captured a message I've been waiting for? They say it "depends on the message sent" - Some message require different return values?

Answer (score 1):

> They say it "depends on the message sent". Some message require different return values?

That is correct. The value to return depends on the message. Each message requires bespoke treatment that differs from message to message.